# VS2008 ASP.net Where are .PDB created?

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging, pdb-files

I have a website in vs2008. I cannot find my .pdb files anywhere after I build.

My build configuration is set to debug. `<compilation debug="true">` is in the web config.

Where is my .pdb? There is nothing in my app_code or bin folder. How do I generate these files?

Comment: I though these were generated when you Build the application, since it's ready to run at that point and those files are required for Debugging. Do you get them if you "Start Debugging" in Visual Studio?

Comment: Nope. I can debug in my local IIS but I don't see the files anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET websites are dynamically compiled on the fly when you first access the web pages, maybe that's why you don't see the .pdb files.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx), the compiled code goes to `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files`. I suppose the pdb (if generated) will end up there too but I don't have Visual Studio 2008 on hand to verify this assumption.